# Is there a DP solution for my subset average problem?

Tags: python, math, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, heuristics

I have a combinatorics problem that I can't solve.

Given a set of vectors and a target vector, return a scalar for each vector, so that the average of the scaled vectors in the set is closest to the target.

Edit: Weights w_i are in range [0, 1]. This is a constrained optimisation problem:

minimise d(avg(w_i * x_i), target)
subject to sum(w_i) - 1 = 0

If i had to name this problem it would be unbounded subset average.

I have looked at the unbounded knapsack and similar problems, but a dynamic programming implementation seems to be impossible due to the interdependence of the numbers.

I also inplemented a genetic algorithm that is able to approximate the weights moderately well, but it takes too long and I was initially hoping to solve the problem using dynamic programming.

Is there any hope?

Comment: If weights `w_i` are in range [0, 1], then this looks like a constrained optimisation problem: minimise `sum(w_i * x_i) - target` subject to `sum(w_i) - 1 = 0`. Here `sum(w_i * x_i)` is the average you're looking for.

Comment: that's what i also got, now how do i implement it whithour bruteforcing all values?

Comment: Something about this seems underspecified. If weights are real numbers in the range [0, 1], isn't a solution to assign a weight 0 to all but the largest element, and a weight of (target)/(max) to the largest element? This is O(n). Or does the sum of the weights have to equal 1?

Comment: AFAIK, such problems can be solved using [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) (the mathematical technique, doesn't have much to do with writing code).

Comment: @Patrick87 i want the average and not the sum. If 5 is my largest element and 2 is my target, i would rather take 80%*1 and 20%*5 = 2 rather than avg(5)=5

Comment: Only the largest and smallest elements need non-zero weights.  Average is (largest*a + smallest*(1-a))/N.  You can get any attainable average by solving for a.  You're either mischaracterizing your problem, or it's just a lot easier than you think.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans does this hold true if i use a set of vectors instead of single numbers? and a target vector.

Comment: I see what you're saying, then yes, you might need to assign weight=1 to the numbers until assigning that weight to the NEXT one would give you N x target, then assign whatever weight gets you exactly to N x target to the next one, then 0 to the remainder. HOWEVER, this does change significantly if you are talking about vectors as opposed to scalars; the target might not even be expressible as a linear combination of vectors in your array unless the vectors in your list cover the vector space. If your list is a basis then you'd expect all of them to need non-zero weights in general.

Comment: @ForceBru I've looked into it, but it seems like I have to convert the minimize function into a maximize one, which makes it 1/sum(x_i*w_i), which is not linear anymore. So that makes it a non-linear programm if i understood it correctly. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: @Marcel, minimising `f(x)` is the same as maximising `-f(x)`, so you don't need to divide, I think

Comment: @Marcel if you're using D-dimensional vectors, then you need to find D+1 of them that make a simplex that contains target*N.  If there isn't one then you can't attain the target value so you should choose the closest point on the convex hull.

Comment: thanks people, i managed to to implement this using scipy's minimize module!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Visualization

In a 2D space the solution to the problem can be represented like this
[image: an image is better than several lines of code]

#### Problem class identification

As recognized by others this is a an optimization problem. You have linear constraints and a convex objective function, it can be cast to [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming), (read [Least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Least_squares) session)

#### Casting to standard form

If you want to minimize the average of `w[i] * x[i]`, this is `sum(w[i] * x[i]) / N`, if you arrange `w[i]` as the elements of a `(1 x N_vectors)` matrix, and each vector `x[i]` as the i-th row of a `(N_vectors x DIM)` matrix, it becomes `w @ X / N_vectors` (with `@` being the matrix product operator).

To cast to that form you would have to construct a matrix so that each rows of `A*x < b` expressing `-w[i] < 0`, the equality is `sum(w) = 1` becomes `sum(w) < 1` and `-sum(w) < -1`. But there there are amazing tools to automate this part.

#### Implementation

This can be readily implemented using [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/), and you don't have to care about expanding all the constraints.

The following function solves the problem and if the vectors have dimension 2 plot the result.

```py
import cvxpy;
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def place_there(X, target):
    # some linear algebra arrangements
    target = target.reshape((1, -1))
    ncols = target.shape[1]
    X = np.array(X).reshape((-1, ncols))
    N_vectors = X.shape[0]
    # variable of the problem
    w = cvxpy.Variable((1, X.shape[0]))
    # solve the problem with the objective of minimize the norm of w * X - T (@ is the matrix product)
    P = cvxpy.Problem(cvxpy.Minimize(cvxpy.norm((w @ X) / N_vectors - target)), [w >= 0, cvxpy.sum(w) == 1])
    
    # here it is solved
    print('Distance from target is: ', P.solve())
    
    # show the solution in a nice plot
    # w.value is the w that gave the optimal solution
    Y = w.value.transpose() * X / N_vectors
    path = np.zeros((X.shape[0] + 1, 2))
    path[1:, :] = np.cumsum(Y, axis=0)
    randColors=np.random.rand( 3* X.shape[0], 3).reshape((-1, 3)) * 0.7
    plt.quiver(path[:-1,0], path[:-1, 1], Y[:, 0], Y[:, 1], color=randColors, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
    plt.plot(target[:, 0], target[:, 1], 'or')
```

And you can run it like this

```py
target = np.array([[1.234, 0.456]]);
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
for i in [1,2,3]:
    X = np.random.randn(20) * 100
    plt.subplot(1,3,i)
    place_there(X, target)
    plt.xlim([-3, 3])
    plt.ylim([-3, 3])
    plt.grid()
plt.show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot.

Comment: You're wellcome! you can indicate this using the buttons to make the site more useful for users that search for answers
https://stackoverflow.com/tour, and to increase reputation of course hehe